# R compilation failed for package fst

Tags: r, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, r-package

I'm trying to install `fst` R package from CRAN but I get error:

```
gcc -I"/path/apps/R/3.5.1-20180807-test/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG 
-fopenmp -I. -Ifstcore -Ifstcore_v1 -Ifstcore/LZ4 -Ifstcore/ZSTD -Ifstcore/ZSTD/common 
-Ifstcore/ZSTD/decompress -Ifstcore/ZSTD/compress 
-I"/path/apps/R/3.5.1-20180807-test/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/r_libs_site/Rcpp/include" 
-I /path/apps/R/static-zlib-gcc6.3/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/include   -fpic  
-I /path/apps/R/static-zlib-gcc6.3/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/include   
-c fstcore/ZSTD/compress/huf_compress.c -o fstcore/ZSTD/compress/huf_compress.o
gcc -I"/path/apps/R/3.5.1-20180807-test/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG 
-fopenmp -I. -Ifstcore -Ifstcore_v1 -Ifstcore/LZ4 -Ifstcore/ZSTD -Ifstcore/ZSTD/common 
-Ifstcore/ZSTD/decompress -Ifstcore/ZSTD/compress 
-I"/path/apps/R/3.5.1-20180807-test/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/r_libs_site/Rcpp/include" 
-I /path/apps/R/static-zlib-gcc6.3/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/include   -fpic  
-I /path/apps/R/static-zlib-gcc6.3/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/include   
-c fstcore/ZSTD/decompress/zstd_decompress.c -o fstcore/ZSTD/decompress/zstd_decompress.o
/tmp/cc0LoSFX.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc0LoSFX.s:7353: Error: no such instruction: `shlx %rax,%rdx,%rax'
/tmp/cc0LoSFX.s:8204: Error: no such instruction: `shlx %rax,%rdx,%rax'
/tmp/cc0LoSFX.s:8608: Error: no such instruction: `shlx %rax,%rdx,%rax'
make: *** [fstcore/ZSTD/decompress/zstd_decompress.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fst’
```

I there any required linux library that can be compiled from source? What else I can do?

EDIT:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/path/apps/gcc/6.3.0/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/path/apps/gcc/6.3.0/x86_64-linux-2.6-rhel6 --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: What is your gcc version?

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel  `6.3.0`

Comment: Something else may be getting on then.

Comment: On CRAN, it says `SystemRequirements: little-endian platform`. Do you have a special type of OS? And it fails on Solaris.

Comment: My OS is RHEL6. And it already installed for R 3.4.3 by previous person so it is possible.

Comment: I would suspect, but do not have proof, that you unusual path to `gcc` has something to do with it. Your generated assembly is out of whack, so `gcc` (which is a "driver" to subprograms) may have gotten versions mixed.  In short. and as I have use `gcc` for 25+ years and I have yet to see that error, I think the error is local to you.

Comment: That assembler errors occur on `fst 0.8.6` only. I installed `fst 0.8.4` without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this here for posterity in case others eventually land on this question when facing similar issues.

It turns out that as far as we can tell, the problem was incompatible versions of the assembler (/usr/bin/as) and gcc (our non-system 6.3.0 installation).

So if you landed here at the end of your rope with no idea why you're seeing these errors, looking into getting a compatible version of the assembler (in linux world this is part of the binutils module/project). Hope that helps.